# Fixing F number in Manual Focus 50mm lens on a D7000

Tags: nikon, aperture, manual-focus, nikon-d7000

I have a 50mm f/1.2, this lens:

http://www.nikonusa.com/Nikon-Products/Product/Camera-Lenses/1435/NIKKOR-50mm-f%252F1.2.html

that I got used from a guy I know. When I mounted it in my D7000 though, I noticed the following:

- the f numbers are displayed as f/0 - f/7, instead of f/1.2 - f/16
- I cannot control the f numbers in the D7000 aperture dial, I have to rotate the len's aperture ring

is this a known issue or is something just wrong with the lens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your menu go to the setup menu (spanner). Near the bottom is non-cpu lens menu option. Here you can set up to 9 lenses manually. This will get the aperture display to show correctly.

For example i have a 50mm 1.4 with which i use an adapter. This lens i have set to number 1. That way when i change f number the camera knows what the setting is.

Comment: I would have to choose this because I was able to display the f numbers correctly. Note however that I can't change them with the D7000 dial

Comment: As Mike says, since the lens has no electronic contacts to communicate with the camera, the camera doesn't know how to set the aperture. You'll have to control the aperture by using the lens's aperture ring.

Answer (score 3):

This lens is totally manual and has no electrical contacts with the camera body.  Therefore the camera doesn't know what to do with it and cannot take control of the aperture in the lens.  You will need to switch your D7000 mode dial to (S)hutter priority mode, set your aperture on the lens itself, and set the shutter speed you wish on the camera body.  If you have auto-ISO enabled, this will take the ISO calculation out of the equation for you, but you may wish to set it yourself so you have control over it..

Comment: Since the camera can't control the aperture, shutter priority doesn't work - the camera will just refuse to take a picture. The only modes that work with non-electronic lenses on the D7000 are M and A.